# Android jersey client doesn't send request to the web-service

Tags: android, rest, jersey-2.0, gradle-dependencies

I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48637658/jersey-client-throws-javax-ws-rs-processingexception-java-net-connectexception/48637728#48637728) and now I have a new problem.
I have updated the IP-address to `10.0.2.2:8080....`, rest everything is the same(Gradle dependencies,etc.).
Request doesn't get sent to the web-service and Jersey throws in some kind of warning.
This is the stacktrace:

> W/Errors: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2
>   service reification failed for
>   [org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.DataSourceProvider] with an
>   exception:
>             MultiException stack 1 of 4
>             java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataSource
>                 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:315)
>                 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.internal.ClassReflectionHelperImpl.getAllMethods(ClassReflectionHelperImpl.java:108)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.findInitializerMethods(Utilities.java:1341)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.DefaultClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(DefaultClassAnalyzer.java:107)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getInitializerMethods(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:242)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getInitMethods(Utilities.java:218)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:145)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:180)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:740)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:694)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:461)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2288)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$1200(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:125)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1373)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$9.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1368)
>                 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.internal.WeakCARCacheImpl.compute(WeakCARCacheImpl.java:116)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1430)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1355)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getAllServiceHandles(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1344)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getServiceHandles(Providers.java:354)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers.getCustomProviders(Providers.java:201)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.(MessageBodyFactory.java:221)
>                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>                 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:272)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:366)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
>                 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
>                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
>                 at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:786)
>                 at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:97)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.RequestProcessingInitializationStage.apply(RequestProcessingInitializationStage.java:67)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages$LinkedStage.apply(Stages.java:308)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
>                 at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:25

**Edit:**
I followed a [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/jersey-2x-client-on-android-take-2) and implemented their way, my warning disappeared but my client still isn't communicating with the server. Also, how does this affect my situation:

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.glassfish.jersey.internal.OsgiRegistry>
```

Does the `Jersey` client work well with Android? If yes, then can appropriate learning materials be provided?

**Edit2**
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/6601614) solution and thereby ditched `Jersey` for good. `Jersey` seems to be having some bugs with Android(I am just speculating. I cannot confirm for sure).

Comment: clean, and rebuild the project, and check the permission of internet in the Manifest, that's is general steps to do. \n but i recommend you to use this library to fetch data REST, HTTP, JSON  https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking  it's really simple

Comment: @medbenjemaa Tried cleaning and rebuilding. Didn't work. I want to use Jersey of this(I could have used Apache HTTP Client but didn't). My web-service also uses Jersey.

Comment: you are not required to use Jersey client, there are so much Libraries and frameworks recommended in android,

Comment: Using a Jersey over some college student's part time project is preferable. I know Jersey will have continued support. How about the other one? Will the person keep up the support for the library from time to time?

Comment: of course, you can join the Issues on GitHub, and you can submit your own issue at any time

Comment: But is it as reliable as an enterprise managed API like Jersey or Apache Http Client?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the dependency explicitly:

```
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
```

Source: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/90)

Comment: I do not want to deal with `AsyncTask` as the request takes some time to process and the response code is obtained around 3-4 secs later which is of importance to me. I understand your point. But when I use `ExecutorService.execute()`, the application simply stops and does nothing with this `W/Error` in the console.

Comment: If the user changes the screen orientation or closes the app while the request is sent, AsyncTask will create problems.

Comment: And that is why I use `ExecutorServices` as recommended by instructors in the Android dev course in Udacity.

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal you are right, ma answer is partial and only explains the NetworkOnMainThreadException exception

Comment: Well, `ExecutorService` takes care of the additional threading stuff. AsyncTask is some kind of an implementation of `ForkJoinThreadPool` which is an implementation of `ThreadPoolExecutor` which in turn is a type of `ExecutorService. So, my threading needs are taken care of. I suspect that I am having problems with the dependency of Jersey.

Comment: Look at the updated answer, seem to be a problem related to Java 9

Comment: I am using java 8

Comment: And after you add `javax.activation` dependency, they will now ask you for `java.awt.image.`